# how to copy folders to a newly created timestamps folder using bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, timestamp

I'm trying to send a copy of folder to newly created timestamp folder using bat

```
bat 'for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do md %%i_%%j_%%k'
```

I want to copy folder from this location

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/jenkins Pipeline/application/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/linux-arm/publish"
```

and paste it in newly created timestamp named folder. I tried to CD to that folder but how can I give the name of the folder?also how to mention time along with date in timestamp folder name?
how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Instead of directly creating the folder following the do, store in a variable  `set "folder=%%i_%%j_%%k"` and then create the folder, do the copy with the var.

Comment: I tried doing it  I ended up creating a folder with the name of folder instead of timestamp name.

Comment: Without you showing us the code not working (in your [edit]ed question), we need a crystal ball ...

Comment: bat 'for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do SET today_fname=%%i_%%j_%%k'

   bat 'for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do md today_fname'

Comment: this created only a folder with a name of today_name instead of date name

Comment: You were already advised to [edit] your question to contain your code. There are no line breaks in comments - so code is hardly readable.

Comment: @deepinside, the second `FOR /F` command makes no sense at all. You don't need another `FOR` command to create the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you can try:

```bat
@echo off
rem Create timestamp:
set "timestamp=%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%"
rem Create folder:
md %timestamp%
xcopy /E "C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/jenkins Pipeline/application/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/linux-arm/publish" "%timestamp%"
```

Hope this helps!