# Create a timestamp folder with today's date and time and copy some folder to it

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, datestamp

I'm trying to create a folder in windows with current timestamp details and copy some folder to it. I tried as below:

```bat
   bat 'for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do SET today_fname=%%i_%%j_%%k'
    bat 'for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do md today_fname'
    bat 'cd %today_fname%'
    bat 'copy "C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/jenkins Pipeline/application/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/os/publish"'
```

It ends up creating a folder with a timestamp name and copying the folder contains to current directory instead of Cd to newly created folder 
I'm trying to create a folder with a name `05_14_18_7_31` and copy the contains present in this location `C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/jenkins Pipeline/application/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/os/publish` to `05_14_18_7_31`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to copy folders to a newly created timestamps folder using bat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994753/how-to-copy-folders-to-a-newly-created-timestamps-folder-using-bat)

Comment: Please don't create a new question, fix/improve/update your existing one and delete this.

Comment: What is that `bat` command? It seems to take a batch file line as a parameter (which makes no sense at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can try:

```bat
@echo off
rem Create datestamp:
set "datestamp=%date:~4,-8%_%date:~7,-5%_%date:~12,2%"
rem Request for me, if you are not using `dd/mm/yy` format, to provide another script for your occassion.
rem Create timestamp:
set "timestamp=%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%"
rem Create folder:
md %datestamp%_%timestamp%
xcopy /E "C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/jenkins Pipeline/application/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/os/publish" "%datestamp%_%timestamp%"
```

Hope this helps!