# How to create a folder with a timestamp and build id as the folder name and copy some files into that folder?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I need to take backup of a few artifacts (.dll files in this case) in a new folder called backup. I want a backup to be taken every time a build happens. I need Jenkins to create a folder with the time stamp and build number as the folder name and then copy the artifacts into that folder.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use the java date:

```
def now = new Date()
def filename = now.format("backup-$BUILD_NUMBER-yyyyMMddHHmm")
```

This will give you a filename of `backup-123-201903291430`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a build step creating that folder, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53545835/6309) (which assumes a Windows agent)

But to have a portable way use/compute/use a timestamp, you can install the [JENKINS ZenTimestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin), which means you will be able to use the `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` environment variable, and use if for your backup folder name.

The build number is part of the [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables): `BUILD_NUMBER`.